# Opening normal buffer in emacs startup

Tags: emacs

When we launch emacs it opens welcome screen.
How to I open a normal buffer and so that I can continue writing (same as in gvim) and it prompt for saving it if it press the "X" close button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your .emacs.  I am no vi user but from your description I think this will do what you want.

```
(setq inhibit-startup-message t
      initial-scratch-message nil
      initial-buffer-choice   "scratch")
```

Comment: "set-buffer-modified-p" to prompt for saving

Comment: I "removed" the * arounf scratch to make emacs prompt for saving if modified (buffer with names starting and ending in * are treated differently)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you should look around adding the following code somewhere in your *~/.emacs*:

```
(switch-to-buffer
  (make-temp-name "temp"))
```

The main idea is to create a new buffer and switch immediately there.

**make-temp-name()** will generate a name for temporary buffer. Since it is not existent it will be created by **switch-to-buffer()**.

Also you might want to have a fixed name of a new buffer, so you can just leave the following:

```
(switch-to-buffer "main")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also launch emacs with the --no-splash command argument (i.e. runemacs.exe --no-splash). Same effect and you don't need to modify the .emacs file if you are not comfortable in doing so.

Comment: Problem with this approach is that OP won't be prompted for saving, since "*scratch*" has a special name